# creating matrix, which reflex properties of a given one with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

when given a N x K matrix with elements from 0 to K, is there an efficient an elegant way to create the following matrix:

```
       #0 | #2 | ... | #K
-------------------------
Row 1   x |  y | ... | z
-------------------------
Row 2   a |  b | ... | d
-------------------------
...
-------------------------
Row N   g |  h | ... | j
```

Where in cell 1,2 should be the amount of 2s in the first row for example.

I know, that a rather inefficient way would be to do this with two for loops, but I was wondering if that is also possible to solve with some matrix / NumPy operations.

Cheers

**EDIT:**
some code might look like this:

```py
x_mod = np.zeros((N,I))
for n in range(N):
   for i in range(I):
      x_mod[n][int(X[n][i])] += 1
```

where X is the original matrix and x_mod the new one.

So for

```
X = 2 3 4 4 0 
    0 1 3 3 2
    1 1 4 2 2
```

the desired result would look like:

```
1 0 1 1 2
1 1 1 2 0
0 2 2 0 1
```

Comment: Can you include an example with two for loops so your intent/rules are clear? And the desired result for `N=3`, `K=5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `np.bincount`. It's fast but unfortunately only works 1D. So one loop is required:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
N,K = 5,6
in_ = rng.integers(0,K,(N,K))
in_
# array([[2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 1],
#        [4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5],
#        [2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3],
#        [5, 5, 0, 4, 4, 5],
#        [1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2]])
out = np.array([np.bincount(i,None,K) for i in in_])
out
# array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
#        [1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]])
```